# AAC Object Type Extraction using Core Audio APIs

Tags: cocoa, core-audio, aac, object-type

Is it possible to determine the Object type of an AAC Audio file using Core Audio APIs? It was told in the documentation that we will get the Object type in the mFormatFlags of Audio Stream Basic Description. But, it has been depreceated from MAC OS X 10.5.